# Spring RestTemplate connection reset

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to consume a REST service with Spring facilities following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) guide but I'm having a problem with the connection.
I want to access with GET method the REST service

http://date.jsontest.com/

I've written this piece of code to consume the service

```
package pack;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;


public class RestUtilityTest {

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({
        "time",
        "milliseconds_since_epoch",
        "date"
    })
    public class DateTime {

        @JsonProperty("time")
        private String time;
        @JsonProperty("milliseconds_since_epoch")
        private Integer milliseconds_since_epoch;
        @JsonProperty("date")
        private String date;
        private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        @JsonProperty("time")
        public String getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        @JsonProperty("time")
        public void setTime(String time) {
            this.time = time;
        }

        @JsonProperty("milliseconds_since_epoch")
        public Integer getMilliseconds_since_epoch() {
            return milliseconds_since_epoch;
        }

        @JsonProperty("milliseconds_since_epoch")
        public void setMilliseconds_since_epoch(Integer milliseconds_since_epoch) {
            this.milliseconds_since_epoch = milliseconds_since_epoch;
        }

        @JsonProperty("date")
        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        @JsonProperty("date")
        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
            return this.additionalProperties;
        }

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
            this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void getTest()
    {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        DateTime datetime = restTemplate.getForObject("http://date.jsontest.com", DateTime.class);

        assertTrue(datetime != null);

    }

}
```

The application throws the following exception stack

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://date.jsontest.com": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:524)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
    at pack.RestUtilityTest.getTest(RestUtilityTest.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:47)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getHttpStatusCode(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:510)
    ... 26 more
```

I tried the REST call with two different network connections so that's not a network connection problem; moreover if I visit the service from a browser I can get the response correctly.

What can be the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you add the jackson libraries, it seems a problem when try to extract the data, as the url is working fine

Comment: Hi @Koitoer, thanks for you reply. I've added the jackson-core, jackson-annotations and jackson-databind (ver 2.2.3) dependencies to my pom.xml.

Comment: And that solve the problem ? or persist

Comment: No, the problem persists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved. The problem is bound to the network connection. The network I belong is firewalled and proxied.
now I'm trying to understand how to make things done with the firewalled network (it's my company one).

Comment: I'm getting a similar error. "ClientAbortException" on the server, but a "SocketException" on the client. Would you be able to tell me what you had to change in the firewall to remove this error?

Comment: Hi @Pytry. I'm not in the same company and now work with other technologies so I'm not able at the moment to reproduce the problem and tell you what is the solution :/ but in general if your network is proxied you have to configure the company proxy in your REST client in order to let it perform the requests through the proxy server