# SocketException: Connection reset -

Tags: java, spring, sockets

I know i am making a simple mistake but cannot figure out whats the mistake.
I have an external API where I need to post certain parameters. I tested this API using Advanced Rest Client and it works fine.
In my server side, i use

> `ResponseEntity<String> response = asyncRestTemplate.getRestOperations().postForEntity(URL, String.class);`

But then this method always throws a exception for the particular URL that i am testing.

I tried other URLS and it works perfectly fine.

Is it possible that the connection reset might occur because the third party who provided me the URL is closing the connection. If it is so, how did Advanced Rest Client manage to get the result?

This is the stack Trace

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://1984.carpal.me/api/v1/quote/":Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:357)
at sg.oddlefnb.common.helper.CarpalApiHelper.getRequestEntityForNewJob(CarpalApiHelper.java:115)
at sg.oddlefnb.common.helper.PartnerApiHelper.postNewJob(PartnerApiHelper.java:54)
at sg.oddlefnb.common.helper.PartnerApiHelper$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b2958cff.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:110)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:81)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:569)
... 12 more
```

Comment: Post the *exact* error message, exception, and stack trace. Not a paraphrase. Never seen 'connection Error' in 18 years of Java.

Comment: @EJP This is all the stack trace i got for that error.

Comment: Do you see the difference between your imaginary 'connection Error' and 'connection reset'?

Comment: Yes I am sorry for the wrong information - @EJP

Comment: Reasons for connection reset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset, similar posts and comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346115/spring-resttemplate-connection-reset (issues with firewall), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509213/getting-connect-reset-exception